# Backslash in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, backslash

I just started to learn python3 2 or 3 days ago so I'm a total noob. I'm learning from a book called How to think like a computer scientist and it uses python2 ann not python3 ... I got stuck when it told me about backslash character... and i can't find anything on the internet ....

```
print("This is a test /n This is a test")
```

What the book says is that i should get something like this:

```
This is a test
This is a test
```

But what I do get is:

```
This is a test /n This is a test
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 4):

The backslash is the **other** slash, `\`:

```
>>> print('This is a test \n This is a test')
This is a test 
 This is a test
```

You are using a **forward** slash, `/`, instead.

Also see the [backslash](/questions/tagged/backslash) [tag wiki excerpt](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/backslash/info):

> The backslash character `\` (not to be confused with slash `/`)...

Answer (score 2):

You are using a forward slash `/` and not a backslash `\`

```
print("This is a test \n This is a test")
This is a test 
This is a test
```